# align textarea and button in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align both textarea and button beside each other in a bootstrap 12 grid system? also, the bottom of my button has an annoying few inches going up.

I tried:

- margin: 0 auto;
- display: flex;
- align-items: center;
- justify-content: center;
- display: inline-block

```css
    .center-div-content {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-div-content">
            <input type="submit" class="btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
          </div>
```

[image: not aligned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [form row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="submit" class="btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b8meg3q/

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to wrap your textarea and button into a row/container div:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
            <input type="submit" class="btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```